# What are the steps to include an rss feed in an android app?

Tags: android, rss

I am new to android and am much more comfortable with C++. However, when researching RSS feeds and how to use them in an android app, I found that they have to be "parsed?" I have never used this before and am now wondering how to include a RSS feed in an app, but any information I have found is contradictory and confusing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For me the simplest way to parse XML feed is using this library

http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/simple-java-xml-parser-sjxp/

Answer (score 0):

you can also check out `XmlPullParser`

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this library:
https://github.com/Pkmmte/PkRSS

It is very easy to use and supports atom and Rss2 feeds by default but supports plugging in your own parser.

For example, this is how you would load a feed from a URL in a background thread:
PkRSS.with(this).load(url).async();

Easy, right? There's more details in the GitHub page.